# Mystery (concurrency/component drawing?) bug in very simple Swing dice program

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, drawing

Sorry for the poor question title, I'm stumped as to the cause of this bug and didn't know how to phrase the question.

I'm learning basic Swing and doing [this exercise](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c6/ex3-ans.html) from the online book Introduction to Programming with Java.

I haven't followed the instructions to the letter and instead am trying to do this:

- have a window that shows a visual representation of two dice
- when you click on one of the dice, it 'rolls' and shows the new value

My implementation:

- a very basic JDie object that extends JPanel
- overridden paintComponent method to draw the die representation
- change die color every time value is changed just for a visual clue
- added a listener to 'roll' the dice when mouse is pressed and then
  repaint

The bug is quite specific:

1. Run the DieTest main method
2. Resize the window to fit the two die
3. Click on the second die to roll it
4. Now click on the first die to roll it
5. The second die's value **changes back to its original value**
6. If you resize the window the second die's value will also change back

If I click on the dice to roll them, **before** I resize the window, the bug won't appear...

I guess I'm making a basic mistake somewhere which has just disguised itself as this strange behaviour.

I've tried to whittle down the code as much as I could, it took ages just working out when the bug appeared and when it didn't:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class JDie extends JPanel {

    private Color color;
    private int value;

    JDie(){

        value = getValue();
        color = Color.BLACK;

        //add listener
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                value = getValue(); //'roll' the die
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    /*private helper methods */
    private int getValue(){
        int v =(int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
        //change color just to show that the
        //value has changed
        color = getRandomColor();
        return v;
    }
    private Color getRandomColor(){
        float r = (float)Math.random();
        float g = (float)Math.random();
        float b = (float)Math.random();
        return new Color(r, g, b);
    }

    //draws the pips for the die
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(color);


        //draw pips
        //set pip size
        int pip_side = 10;
        switch(value){
        case 1:
            g.fillRect(3*pip_side, 3*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            break;
        case 2:
            g.fillRect(5*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            g.fillRect(pip_side, 5*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            break;
        case 3:
            g.fillRect(5*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            g.fillRect(pip_side, 5*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            g.fillRect(3*pip_side, 3*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            break;
        case 4:
            g.fillRect(pip_side, pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            g.fillRect(5*pip_side, 5*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            g.fillRect(5*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            g.fillRect(pip_side, 5*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            break;
        case 5:
            g.fillRect(pip_side, pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            g.fillRect(5*pip_side, 5*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            g.fillRect(5*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            g.fillRect(pip_side, 5*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            g.fillRect(3*pip_side, 3*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            break;
        case 6:
            g.fillRect(pip_side, pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            g.fillRect(5*pip_side, 5*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            g.fillRect(5*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            g.fillRect(pip_side, 5*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            g.fillRect(pip_side, 3*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            g.fillRect(5*pip_side, 3*pip_side, pip_side, pip_side);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public class DieTest extends JFrame{

    DieTest(){
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        add(new JDie());
        add(new JDie());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //if I set the size smaller than the JDie is displaying
        //and resize the window before 'rolling' the dice
        //then the bug appears...?!
        setSize(80, 80);
        //setting the size larger than both JDie
        //and it works fine whether you resize or not
//      setSize(200, 200);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DieTest();
            }

        });
    }

}
```

--------------EDIT-----------------

Running the code again, I've now noticed it doesn't happen 100% of the time, but the bug is still there. Here's a gif that I just took of it bugging that might illustrate the problem better:

[image: Strange bug]

You can clearly see the original value with the original color is being redrawn when I click the first die again.
When I resize the window, the second die's value jumps back one, to the previous value it had...
I really don't understand this...

---------------EDIT 2---------------------

- Tried the same code on another computer (mac) but couldn't replicate
  the problem.
- Compiled and ran the code on my computer outside of Eclipse, couldn't
  replicate the problem.
- Ran the code that Eclipse had compiled from command line, only got
  the problem once, couldn't replicate it today.
- Running the code from Eclipse, I still get the problem about 1 in
  5-10 times? If it doesn't show up on the first 'pass' as it were, it
  doesn't show up at all. The gif illustrates it well.

So it seems my computer set up has some bearing on this as well, details are:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1
- Java Version 7 Update 51
- Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 3 (64 bit)

This is a tricky one as I know longer know whether it's my code or some other program's that is causing the problem. As a newb how can I know whether any future problems are a result of my bad programming or something else... frustrating.

----------EDIT 3-----------

As a quick investigation into the concurrency side of things:
I set all the instance fields to volatile
I set all the methods including paintComponent to synchronized
I removed the Math.random() call (although I read another thread saying that this was the thread safe implementation) and replaced it with instance Random objects instead

Unfortunately I still get the visual switchback.

Another thing I've noticed is that it seems to be happening a lot less often now about 1 in 10 times. I keep on getting my hopes up that it's fixed, and then the next attempt bugs again. In my original program I was working on, it seemed more like 1 in 3 (I've completely changed that program now so don't have it to hand).

--------EDIT 4---------
I have come up with a slightly more stripped down version which no longer uses any random values and still produces the visual switchback. It seems to happen more often with this code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ColorPanelsWindow extends JFrame{

    class ColorPanel extends JPanel {

        //color starts off black
        //once it is changed should never be 
        //black again
        private Color color = Color.BLACK;

        ColorPanel(){
            //add listener
                    //click on panel to rotate color
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    color = rotateColor();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }
        //rotates the color black/blue > red > green > blue
        private Color rotateColor(){
            if (color==Color.BLACK || color == Color.BLUE)
                return Color.RED;
            if (color==Color.RED)
                return Color.GREEN;
            else return Color.BLUE;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        }
    }
ColorPanelsWindow(){
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));
    add(new ColorPanel());
    add(new ColorPanel());
    //the size must be set so that the window is too small
    // and the two ColorPanels are overlapping
    setSize(40, 40);
            //setSize(300, 200);

    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ColorPanelsWindow();
        }

    });
}

}
```

A couple of observations:

- afaict the panels must be overlapping at first
- if I use a flow layout, increase the size of the window, or any way
  that stops the panels from overlapping initially, then I don't seem
  to get the problem (or maybe it just happens much less often?)

Comment: I tried your code and followed your instructions, but I could not reproduce the bug. The dice only change if I click into the frame, but not when I resize it. Are you sure you do not accidentally click somewhere into the frame when you try to resize the window? Because, as it currently stands, the dice also roll when I click below or beside them.

Comment: @Múna Thanks for testing it. I've now noticed that it doesn't happen all the time, but it definitely isn't just an error of where I'm clicking. I added a gif to illustrate it better.

Comment: tough one (read: no idea what's happening ;-) - but I can reproduce the error following the steps as described. No time to dig deeper, just a rather weird observation: when I click into the first - producing the visual switch-back in the second - the second's paintComponent is _not_ called again. Independent on layoutManager, or random ...

Comment: quickly tested against jdk6: all well, so looks like something introduced in jdk7 (my version on win is 7u45) - which would explain @Trashgod not seeing it on mac with a different jdk implementation

Comment: happens in jdk8 as well ...

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks a lot for trying this out. I'm really glad someone else can replicate this and it's not just me going mad! I also noticed that it didn't seem to be calling the paintComponent again, I put a bunch of print statements and they weren't printed out when the visual switch back happened. I'll update the question with my latest info.

Comment: forgot to mention a quick hack: call getParent().repaint in the mouseListener (nasty, but seems to work). You might consider filing a bug report ... if you have the nerves, I gave up a couple a years agon ;-)

Comment: When I have a moment I'm going to try and whittle down the code a bit more to see if I can't isolate the bug a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, yes, I know exactly what you're talking about. I suffered from the same effect on my application.

Although I had a really hard time figuring out the reason, which I'm - even now - not sure if it's indeed what I think; that's happening,
(too technical and not appropriate to post that all here) I *did* fix it, and I don't even know why it works.

So, instead of repainting the component itself, repaint its container (or its container's container - if still didn't fix).

```
getParent().repaint();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well thank you very much for that, solved it instantly! I haven't looked at that code for a while now, but I'm still very intrigued as to why it acts the way it does. I might post another specific question about it when I have the time.

Comment: I posted the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222976/why-does-this-this-swing-bug-occur-when-using-repaint-and-not-with-getparent

Answer (score 4):

Like Múna, I can't reproduce your findings, but I have a few observations:

- Override [`getPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) to define the initial geometry.
- Define constants that enforce the geometric relationships.
- Use a [layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) that respects the preferred size, e.g. `FlowLayout` to to see the effect.
- Use `Color.getHSBColor()` to get various saturated hues.
- Use a single instance of `Random` as needed.

Addendum: The intermittent nature and platform variability of the problem strongly suggest incorrect synchronization. In the original program, both dice share a single, static instance of `Random` owned by `Math`; in the example below, each die has it's own instance. Note also that resizing the frame indirectly invokes `paintComponent()`.

[image]

As tested:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DieTest extends JFrame {

    DieTest() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(new JDie());
        add(new JDie());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DieTest();
            }
        });
    }

    private static class JDie extends JPanel {

        private static final int SIDE = 32;
        private static final Random r = new Random();
        private Color color;
        private int value = getValue();
        private final Timer t = new Timer(500, null);

        JDie() {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(color, color.darker()));
            value = getValue();
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    value = getValue();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            t.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    value = getValue();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(SIDE * 7, SIDE * 7);
        }

        private int getValue() {
            color = Color.getHSBColor(r.nextFloat(), 1, 1);
            return r.nextInt(6) + 1;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(color);
            switch (value) {
                case 1:
                    g.fillRect(3 * SIDE, 3 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    g.fillRect(5 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    g.fillRect(SIDE, 5 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    g.fillRect(5 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    g.fillRect(SIDE, 5 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    g.fillRect(3 * SIDE, 3 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    g.fillRect(SIDE, SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    g.fillRect(5 * SIDE, 5 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    g.fillRect(5 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    g.fillRect(SIDE, 5 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    g.fillRect(SIDE, SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    g.fillRect(5 * SIDE, 5 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    g.fillRect(5 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    g.fillRect(SIDE, 5 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    g.fillRect(3 * SIDE, 3 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    g.fillRect(SIDE, SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    g.fillRect(5 * SIDE, 5 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    g.fillRect(5 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    g.fillRect(SIDE, 5 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    g.fillRect(SIDE, 3 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    g.fillRect(5 * SIDE, 3 * SIDE, SIDE, SIDE);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for testing it trashgod, I went back and made a gif of it bugging to illustrate it better. It's very strange and took me a couple of times to get this time round. Also thanks a lot for your suggestions on the code, I'll definitely implement them later. I actually tried to strip out as much of the code as I could to just illustrate the bug on its own.

Comment: I'd expect doubles or a repeat throw about one click in six. Are you seeing  a different result?

Comment: I haven't really noticed anything strange in the pattern of random values returned. I'm guessing that the random values or some concurrency problem might have something to do with the bug which is why it only shows up so sporadically. I haven't been able to reproduce the bug on other computers and only once outside Eclipse... tis driving me crazy! I've edited my question to include extra info.

Comment: I notice that your dice share a single, static instance of `Random` owned by `Math`; each of mine has it's own instance. Note also that resizing the frame indirectly invokes `paintComponent()`.

Comment: don't think that it is related to synch of random (changing that has no effect) - currently assume it's a jdk bug, see my comments to the question. Just guessing, though, and no solution :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried replacing the random calls, but it didn't solve it. I updated the question to reflect this. It really does seem a synchronization problem, but maybe on the jdk's end like kleopatra suggests? I'm reminded of Bruce Eckel's comments on synchronization bugs in his book, 'Thinking in Java' : trial and error is no good, you have to really understand synchronization and be able to thing through the problems theoretically because the practical effects that you see are too random and rare to manage. Or at least that's what I understood!

Comment: @user3303123: I agree; the [*happens-before*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) relation offers a way to reason about a particular program. I believe that my example is correctly synchronized in the sense Eckel and the JLS mean. Does it evince the same behavior on your platform?